# Argument list too long to when loading an eBPF program via the bpf syscall

Tags: c, go, bpf, ebpf

I am trying to load an eBPF program via the `bpf` syscall in Go but am seeing an error returned from the syscall. In order to restrict the problem I am using the following minimal eBPF program, which does nothing:

```
struct task_group {};
```

The important parts of the Go program are as follows:

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("bpf/bbf_tty.o")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Print(err)
}

progType := BPF_PROG_TYPE_KPROBE
insns := unsafe.Pointer(&b)
insnCnt := len(b)

lba := struct {
    progType    uint32
    pad0        [4]byte
    insnCnt     uint32
    pad1        [4]byte
    insns       uint64
    license     uint64
    logLevel    uint32
    pad2        [4]byte
    logSize     uint32
    pad3        [4]byte
    logBuf      uint64
    kernVersion uint32
    pad4        [4]byte
}{
    progType:    uint32(progType),
    insns:       uint64(uintptr(insns)),
    insnCnt:     uint32(insnCnt),
    license:     uint64(uintptr(0)),
    logBuf:      uint64(uintptr(0)),
    logSize:     uint32(0),
    logLevel:    uint32(0),
    kernVersion: uint32(4),
}

ret, _, err := unix.Syscall(
    unix.SYS_BPF,
    bpf.BPF_PROG_LOAD,
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&lba)),
    unsafe.Sizeof(lba),
)

if ret != 0 || err != 0 {
    return fmt.Errorf("Unable to load program: %s", err)
}
```

However the error that's getting returned is `Unable to load program: argument list too long`. Why is this? Or better yet, how can I get a more verbose output to find out the root cause of the issue?

From [here](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/bpf/syscall.c) there are only three places that `E2BIG` (argument list too long) gets returned from the `bpf` syscall, but none of them seem to fit.

I can provide a more complete version of my code if needed, I just tried to strip out the irrelevant parts for brevity.

To help with recreating this issue, I have included my full BPF program below. The full repo is [here](https://github.com/dippynark/kubepf/tree/add-ebpf-program):

```
#include <node_config.h>
#include <netdev_config.h>
#include <filter_config.h>

#include <bpf/api.h>

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>

#include "lib/utils.h"
#include "lib/common.h"
#include "lib/maps.h"
#include "lib/xdp.h"
#include "lib/eps.h"
#include "lib/events.h"

// define structures
enum pid_type
{
    PIDTYPE_PID,
    PIDTYPE_PGID,
    PIDTYPE_SID,
    PIDTYPE_MAX,
    // only valid to __task_pid_nr_ns() 
    __PIDTYPE_TGID
};
struct upid {
  int nr;
};
struct pid
{
  struct upid numbers[1];
};
struct pid_link
{
  struct pid *pid;
};
struct task_group {
};
struct task_struct {
  struct task_struct *group_leader;
  struct pid_link           pids[PIDTYPE_MAX];
};
struct sid_t {
    int sid;
};

#define BUFSIZE 256
struct tty_write_t {
    int count;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    unsigned int sessionid;
};

// define maps
struct bpf_elf_map __section_maps active_sids = {
    .type       = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
    .size_key   = sizeof(struct sid_t),
    .size_value = sizeof(uint64_t),
};

struct bpf_elf_map __section_maps tty_writes = {
    .type       = BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERF_EVENT_ARRAY,
};

// save_sid saves a sessionid generated from a call
// to setsid to the active_sids map
int save_sid(struct pt_regs *ctx) {

    struct sid_t sid_struct = {};
    int sid = PT_REGS_RC(ctx);
    uint64_t time_ns = bpf_ktime_get_ns();

    sid_struct.sid = sid;

    bpf_map_update(&sid_struct, &time_ns);

    return 0;

}

//int kprobe__tty_write(struct pt_regs *ctx, struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t count)
int kprobe__tty_write(struct pt_regs *ctx, struct file *file, const char *buf, size_t count)
{
    struct task_struct *task;
    struct pid_link pid_link;
    struct pid pid;
    int sessionid;

    // get current sessionid
    task = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();
    bpf_probe_read(&pid_link, sizeof(pid_link), (void *)&task->group_leader->pids[PIDTYPE_SID]);
    bpf_probe_read(&pid, sizeof(pid), (void *)pid_link.pid);
    sessionid = pid.numbers[0].nr;

    // build session struct key
    struct sid_t sid_key;
    sid_key.sid = sessionid;

    // if sid does not exist in our map then return
    //u64 *time_ns = active_sids.lookup(&sid_key);
    //if (!time_ns) {
    //    return 0;
    //}

    // bpf_probe_read() can only use a fixed size, so truncate to count
    // in user space:
    struct tty_write_t tty_write = {};
    bpf_probe_read(&tty_write.buf, BUFSIZE, (void *)buf);
    if (count > BUFSIZE) {
        tty_write.count = BUFSIZE;
    } else {
        tty_write.count = count;
    }

    // add sessionid to tty_write structure and submit
    tty_write.sessionid = sessionid;
    bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &tty_write, sizeof(tty_write));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this a GO or C code problem?  You should take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: Strictly Go - I tagged C as I'm importing the C package. It's not really a problem in any language, it's a error returned from the `bpf` syscall

Comment: But I will read those things, I guess I haven't included enough detail for it to be answered properly

Comment: @dippynark Could you add the C code of the BPF program (or the bytecode if you didn't write it in C)? This error usually comes from an incorrect use of BPF helpers.

Comment: @jwdonahue I've added back the C tag as it uses both C and Go and I'm not sure where the root cause is

Comment: @pchaigno I've added the BPF program I'm trying to load with a bit more of a description of the problem - the BPF program does nothing to try and narrow down where the issue is coming from

Comment: I think the padding in your Go program's `lba` struct is throwing things off. The C struct `{ __u32   prog_type; __u32 insn_cnt;...}` doesn't have padding between those first two members (verified with a small C program). So you're passing a struct that is bigger than expected, and the kernel code in `check_uarg_tail_zero` checks all the excess bytes and returns E2BIG if any are nonzero.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Good spot, I put in padding because some of the input attributes needed to be 'aligned', but I'm now getting a different error: invalid argument. The definition is `EINVAL: For BPF_PROG_LOAD, indicates an attempt to load an invalid program. eBPF programs can be deemed invalid due to unrecognized instructions, the use of reserved fields, jumps out of range, infinite loops or calls of unknown functions.` from https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-dev/bpf.2.en.html#ERRORS

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I tried inserting the program https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/bpf/test_overhead_kprobe_kern.c compiled using the provided Makefile, so I'm fairly sure there isn't an error in the program, but I received `invalid argument` again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is the way you try to load the BPF bytecode.

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("bpf/bbf_tty.o")
```

I have never used Go, but from what I understand this reads all the bytes from the ELF object file, without any specific processing, and feed them to the `bpf()` syscall later in your code.

The thing is, this is not how things work: when it compiles into eBPF, clang puts your program into *one* particular section (by default, `.text`, but you could specify another name). In addition, if you use eBPF maps, some magic happens (“map relocation”) so that your ELF file can embed map info, and your userspace program calling to `bpf()` can retrieve it and send it to the kernel.

So when you load the whole file to send it to `bpf()`, you load your actual bytecode, plus all ELF sections and header. The kernel probably does not like it much. I don't know how to fix it in Go, but here are some pointers that might be helpful:

- libbpf, a C library that can load eBPF programs from the ELF files: located [in the kernel tree](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davem/net-next.git/tree/tools/lib/bpf/libbpf.c).
- Gobpf, some framework to use eBPF programs with Go ([link](https://github.com/iovisor/gobpf)). I've never used it, but surely they would have some code to load programs from object files?

Comment: I've got my program working with Gobpf but had issues when moving it into a container (I want to run distributed tracing with Kubernetes) so tried to go back to basics and implement everything myself through the syscall - thanks for pointing that out though, I'll try those things asap

Comment: started using gobpf's elf package instead of the bcc package and it works nicely without having to compile the BPF program on the fly :)

Answer (score 1):

> **See @Qeole's answer for the actual cause of this error message.**

You need a non-empty BPF program. Otherwise, you will fail the following precondition in [`bpf_prog_load`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.15.1/source/kernel/bpf/syscall.c#L1137):

```
if (attr->insn_cnt == 0 || attr->insn_cnt > BPF_MAXINSNS)
    return -E2BIG;
```

Your current compiled BPF program appears to be empty since it does not contain any function. Therefore, `attr->insn_cnt` is null.

---

**Details** I've checked that `attr->insn_cnt` is actually null:

```
$ cat tmp.c 
struct task_group {};
$ clang -O2 -target bpf -c tmp.c -o tmp.o
$ ls -lh tmp.o 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul paul 368 févr.  7 11:21 tmp.o
$ readelf -x .text tmp.o

Section '.text' has no data to dump.
```

The object file is not empty but its .text section, which should contains the BPF instructions, is. If I run `readelf -x .text tmp.o` on one of my own programs I get a hexdump, as expected.

Comment: @pchaigo `isnt_cnt` is not non-zero; even with just a task_struct definition it is over 300 bytes big. I've tried with a full program of about 1KB in size with the same issue

Comment: Hm, I'll run some more checks. What is 300B big? The bpf/bbf_tty.o file?

Comment: Yeah, even with just that task_group struct above. I guess there's come default overhead that's added - the details of C compilation is not one of my strong points

Comment: I'm using CLANG for the compilation of the BPF program in the same way as Cilium do here: https://github.com/cilium/cilium/blob/master/bpf/Makefile

Comment: @pchaigo have you managed to recreate the error at all? I realise there's a lot of stuff around the edges that's missing, just didn't want to clog the question

Comment: I've added details in my answer to show that there are actually 0 instructions for that BPF program. Hope that help.

Comment: If you have a minimal test case from your full program, I can check again.

Comment: Dumb question (never used Go): what does `ioutil.ReadFile("bpf/bbf_tty.o")` do? Does it retrieve a specific section from the ELF file and perform eBPF map relocation, or do you just feed all the bytes as read from the file to the `bpf()` syscall?

Comment: Hm, right. Missed that. I think you're on to something Qeole :)
It just reads the bytes. Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: @Qeole Yeah it just feeds to object file byte for byte into the `bpf` syscall, should you instead strip off any ELF headers etc. so you're left with just the text section?

Comment: @pchaigno Nice one showing that the .text section is empty - I guess the compiler is stripping out unused parts. My full program definitely will have had a .text section though - I'll post that now

Comment: @pchaigno I have no idea how to fix that in Go :-) Please proceed if you know what function/lib to use. Or there is the Gobpf thing, maybe.

Comment: @pchaigno I've included my full BPF program at the bottom of the question - using your technique I can see it does have a .text section, so I don't *think* that's this issue in this case

Comment: @Qeole Honestly, I think pointing to the issue and how you found it is enough. We're not supposed to write programs for other developers. This is a debugging question ;)

Comment: @pchaigno yeah true, but simplifying my problem (by reducing the BPF program) has actually changed what the problem is. The problem with my original BPF program still remains - the full code is here if you have any extra time https://github.com/dippynark/kubepf/tree/add-ebpf-program - I will keep trying. Thanks for your help