# Invalid argument (EINVAL) when trying to load a BPF program

Tags: c, linux, bpf, ebpf

I am trying to load a BPF program using the `bpf` syscall but I am receiving `invalid argument` (EINVAL) on return. From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bpf.2.html#ERRORS), the possible reasons for this are:

```
EINVAL

For BPF_PROG_LOAD, indicates an attempt to load an invalid program. 
eBPF programs can be deemed invalid due to unrecognized instructions, 
the use of reserved fields, jumps out of range, infinite loops or calls 
of unknown functions.
```

So it seems there is something wrong with my BPF program. My BPF program is as follows:

```
#include <uapi/linux/bpf.h>

int prog(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Which surely cannot have anything wrong with it.

I am compiling with the `Makefile` [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/bpf/Makefile) (I removed most of the code from `test_overhead_kprobe_kern.c` to give a very simple program for testing).

What could be wrong with my program that caused it to get rejected?

`uname -a`: Linux ubuntu1710 4.13.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 09:13:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

My full userspace code (in Go) is as follows:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(char* s) {
 printf("%s\n", s);
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "unsafe"

    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"

    "github.com/cilium/cilium/pkg/bpf"
)
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

const (
    bufferSize           = 256
    sessionIDHTTPHeader  = "X-Session-ID"
    defaultServerAddress = "localhost"
    defaultPort          = 5050
)

const (
    BPF_PROG_TYPE_UNSPEC        = 0
    BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER = 1
    BPF_PROG_TYPE_KPROBE        = 2
    BPF_PROG_TYPE_SCHED_CLS     = 3
    BPF_PROG_TYPE_SCHED_ACT     = 4
)

type ttyWrite struct {
    Count     int32
    Buf       [bufferSize]byte
    SessionID int32
}

func main() { 

  //for i := 0; i < 6; i++ {
    //b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fmt.Sprintf("bpf/test%d.o", i))
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("bpf/bpf_tty.o")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }

    err = loadProgram(BPF_PROG_TYPE_KPROBE, unsafe.Pointer(&b), len(b))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", err)
    }
    //}

}

func loadProgram(progType int, insns unsafe.Pointer, insnCnt int) error {

    licenseBuf := "GPL"
    licenseStr := C.CString(licenseBuf)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(licenseStr))

    logStr := C.CString("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(logStr))

    lba := struct {
        progType uint32
        //pad0        [4]byte
        insnCnt uint32
        //pad1        [4]byte
        insns    uint64
        license  uint64
        logLevel uint32
        //pad2        [4]byte
        logSize uint32
        //pad3    [4]byte
        logBuf  uint64
        kernVersion uint32
        //pad4        [4]byte
    }{
        progType: uint32(progType),     
        insnCnt:  uint32(insnCnt),
        insns:    uint64(uintptr(insns)),
        license:  uint64(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(licenseStr))),      
        logLevel: uint32(1),
        logSize:  uint32(50),
        logBuf:   uint64(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(logStr))),
        //logBuf: uint64(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(bufStr))),
        // /usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
        kernVersion: uint32(265485),
    }

    ret, _, err := unix.Syscall(
        unix.SYS_BPF,
        bpf.BPF_PROG_LOAD,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&lba)),
        unsafe.Sizeof(lba),
    )

    //fmt.Printf("%s\n", logBuf)
    //cs := C.CString("XXXXXXXXXX")
    C.print(logStr)
    //fmt.Printf("%c\n", *logStr)

    if ret != 0 || err != 0 {
        //fmt.Printf("%#v %d\n", logBuf, unsafe.Sizeof(lba))
        return fmt.Errorf("Unable to load program: ret: %d: %s", int(ret), err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you add `SEC("kprobe/__set_task_comm")` back?

Comment: I had to add `#include "bpf_helpers.h"` but no it still doesn't work, with the same error :/

Comment: Ok. You had no warning during compilation? It should complain about the missing `#include <linux/ptrace.h>` for `struct pt_regs` AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah I had a warning, but it still compiled without an error. I added back `#include <linux/ptrace.h>` and it compiled without warnings or errors but I received the same error from the `bpf` syscall

Comment: Ok. What about the two last lines you removed, about the version and the license? Have you tried with those?

Comment: nah same error still :/ I had to add `#include <linux/version.h>`

Comment: What code are you using to load and attach your program? Do you get any output from the kernel verifier? Have you tried providing a non-null `log-level` to `bpf()`? (The latter should not be needed if I remember correctly, verifier should print error messages anyway if the problem occurs at this stage… but just in case.)

Comment: I've tried providing a log_level buffer but it never gets filled - it may be an issue with the way I'm doing it. The code I'm using to load the program is the same as the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48653164/argument-list-too-long-to-when-loading-an-ebpf-program-via-the-bpf-syscall?noredirect=1#comment84339960_48653164

Comment: So you tried a non-empty buffer and provided its length to `bpf()`, along with a non-null `log-level`, right? And you get nothing in this buffer after `bpf()` returns? Since last question, did you manage to fix your loader to get the correct eBPF bytecode instructions to feed to `bpf()`, by the way?

Comment: @Qeole Yeah, with log-level=1, and the buffer contains the same characters as what I initialised it with :/ Haven't managed to get `bpf` to return successfully yet. I did add the `kern_version` parameter, which is only checked when the program type is `kprobe` (which it is in my case) and I got `EPERM` so had start running my program with `sudo` (`CAP_SYS_ADMIN` is required as expected) - so the `EINVAL` errors I was getting previously may have been due to the `kern_version` being set to 0, hard to tell. The error went back to being `EINVAL` again when using `sudo`

Comment: @Qeole anyway, my current plan is to understand and modify [tcptracer-bpf](https://github.com/weaveworks/tcptracer-bpf) which seems to be doing something very close to what I want

Comment: @dippynark Could you add your userspace code, with the call to the bpf syscall?

Comment: Are you sure you have a BPF C compiler available, and that you're using it to compile that program? BPF programs aren't native executables.

Comment: @pchaigno sorry for the late reply - I've added my full userspace code to the bottom of the question. I've left the comments in as it might be useful to what I've tried. As Qeole mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48653164/argument-list-too-long-to-when-loading-an-ebpf-program-via-the-bpf-syscall?noredirect=1#answer-48661976) it may be the case that I'm passing in a load of ELF headers which the kernel doesn't like, still need to look into that

Comment: @duskwuff yeah, I'm compiling the BPF program with the `Makefile` linked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Qeole pointed out in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48661976/6884590), your userspace Go program needs to extract the BPF instructions (`.text` section) from the object file. Otherwise, the kernel will try to interpret the binary content as BPF instructions and inevitably fail.

Comment: started using [gobpf's](https://github.com/iovisor/gobpf) elf package to load the program and it now works, thanks for the explanation though - changed the chosen answer for my other question to Qeole's answer too :)